# Where should I call the API ? (Thunks?, Component ? )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a question about React with Redux, all concepts of redux they have me confused bit, I've watch tutorial or papers where in actions file add thunk functions for all process of call api loading, success or fail and then save result in store, my question is when I must do this or just call api in my component ? is a good practice call API in my componet ?

Thank!

Sorry, I don't speak english very well, I hope they have understood.

Comment: Short answer - no... All ajax requests should be done in actions...

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options when it comes to api calls in react/redux. Here's two that I've used:

1.Make all calls in action creator with redux-thunk:

```
const action = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const {data} = await axios.get('/endpoint');
        dispatch({type: DO_SOMETHING, payload: data})
    } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
    }
}
```

This method works well and there's nothing wrong with it. The problem is that you end up writing a lot of boilerplate code. It also means that your action creators aren't pure functions. Pure actions are generally easier to test and reason about.

2.Use an action as a command that contains relevant api call information and a success handler that is invoked with the response. You can then write middlware that handles all your api calls in one place. This makes it easier to handle errors and keeps action creators pure. This method is a little more setup but it's worth it in the long run.

action creator that component dispatches:

```
const getSomthing = () => ({
    type: API,
    payload: {
        call: {
            url: "/endpoint",
            method: "get"
        },
        success: data => ({type: DO_SOMETHING, payload: data})
    }
});
```

middlware that handles api calls:

```
const api = ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => async action => {
    if (action.type !== API) {
    return next(action);
    }
    const { call, success, failure } = action.payload;

    try {
        const { data } = await axios(call);
        if (success) {
            dispatch(success(data));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
    }
};
```

You can then apply this middleware to your store.

Boris Dinkevich uses this approach. I'll link to his talk about it which is worth a watch regardless of which method you use. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gjiu7Lgdg3s

Comment: But the problem with this whole "Do Ajax Calls in Actions Idea" is that, you will be assuming all data that comes from those APIs is worthy of storage in the Redux store. Let me remind people that Redux is meant for Common State... Not a component Specific state. IF you're using it to store data relevant to a specific component, that's a bad idea. And this applies to both API calls, why split your API call to an action if what the call returns is only relevant to the component making the call? Lol, and at the end, all they'll ever say as an advantage is readability.